# Need to read multiple data sets for multiple Users using a single CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to work on the below scenario.

In my test plan, I have 200 users; each user contains 100 records, but I need to use a single csv file for all users.

i.e., my CSV will contain 20000 different records, and each user needs to run 100 records.

I used 200 different CSV files, and it is working, but now I need only one CSV file to get the data for all the users.

Comment: have you considered preloading all of your data elements into a queue?   As each user needs a value, it goes to the queue to retrieve one.   When the queue is empty, the user terminates.   Check out the Amazon SQS free tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is going for an alternative CSV Data Set Config implementation, i.e. [baolu-csv-data-file-config](https://github.com/LeeBaul/baolu-csv-data-file-config)

It has capability of allocating a subset of lines to each virtual user:

[image]

This way you can get confidence that a single user won't run more than 100 records.

The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Comment: I tried baolu-csv-data-file-config, and I can see the users are picking the records based on the set block size values that I am giving, but I am seeing the values taken randomly instead of sequentially.

Comment: I want the first 100 records to be taken by user 1, the 101 to 200 records to be taken by user 2, and so on. I need 200 Users.


Do we have any options for that in the baolu CSV data set configuration or any other in Jmeter ?